# File create and file write in php

Tags: php

I want to create file called info.php. I'm using xampp server and this is my code:

```
<?
if (file_exists('./info.php')) {
header('Location: ./public/index.php');
exit();
}else{

fopen('info.php', 'c');
$handle = fopen('info.php' , 'w+') or die('Unable to create file');

$username = "$username =" .$_POST['Username'];
$password = "$pass = " .$_POST['password'];
$webname = "$wbname = " .$_POST['webname'];
$webtitle = "$wbtit = " .$_POST['webtitle'];

fwrite($handle, '<?');
fwrite($handle, $username);
fwrite($handle, $password);
fwrite($handle, $webname);
fwrite($handle, $webtitle);
fclose();
}
```

I also read the PHP manual and tryed w3schools code but still nothing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [how-to-ask] Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (file_exists('./info.php')) {
header('Location: ./public/index.php');
exit();
}else{
    $handle = fopen('info.php', 'w');

    $username = "$username =" .$_POST['Username'];
    $password = "$pass = " .$_POST['password'];
    $webname = "$wbname = " .$_POST['webname'];
    $webtitle = "$wbtit = " .$_POST['webtitle'];

    fwrite($handle, '<?');
    fwrite($handle, $username);
    fwrite($handle, $password);
    fwrite($handle, $webname);
    fwrite($handle, $webtitle);
    fclose($handle);
}
```

This code is working fine . You just need to set write access on your folder like this:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 FOLDER_NAME/   - using terminal
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code.

```
<?php

if (file_exists('./info.php')) {
header('Location: ./public/index.php');
exit();
}else{
$handle = fopen('info.php' , 'w+') or die('Unable to create file');

$username = '$username ="' .$_POST['Username'].'";';
$password = '$pass = "' .$_POST['password'].'";';
$webname = '$wbname = "' .$_POST['webname'].'";';
$webtitle = '$wbtit = "' .$_POST['webtitle'].'";';

fwrite($handle, '<?php ');
fwrite($handle, $username);
fwrite($handle, $password);
fwrite($handle, $webname);
fwrite($handle, $webtitle);
fwrite($handle, ' ?>');
fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: This answer would help others understand what it is you did by explaining what it is you changed in their code to make it work.

Comment: i changed double quotes enclosing the variable to single quotes and added file handle to fclose()

Answer (score -2):

Replace your code with this, hope it works

```
if (file_exists('./info.php')) {
header('Location: ./public/index.php');
exit();
}else{
    $handle = fopen('info.php', 'w');

    $username = "$username =" .$_POST['Username'];
    $password = "$pass = " .$_POST['password'];
    $webname = "$wbname = " .$_POST['webname'];
    $webtitle = "$wbtit = " .$_POST['webtitle'];

    fwrite($handle, '<?');
    fwrite($handle, $username);
    fwrite($handle, $password);
    fwrite($handle, $webname);
    fwrite($handle, $webtitle);
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: No still doesn't work

Comment: Please show me error

Comment: File creation code working fine, may be your other code is not working check properly, don't give negative rating.